React accessibility issues
I have a question regarding the screen reader reading React pages. Say, on the home page, it renders component A. When clicking a button on the page, the route changes and it switches to another page, which renders component B. The component B has buttons, links, textboxes, etc. The SR reads those buttons, etc. as pure text.
component B
return <button onClick={...} ...>Click me</button>
I'm loading the page within an aria-live region since it is dynamic content. When the page loads, the screen reader reads it as text "click me" instead of "button - click me". I expect it to do the latter. When tabbing to the button, the screen reader reads it correctly as button.
One solution is to set focus to those buttons, etc. But it's not ideal. I am wondering if there are any other solutions?
Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

This doesn't answer your question, but— If you have clickable text that navigates the user to a new page, it should be a link and not a button.

@sean, thanks, but I was trying to say after the route changes. The issue is on the second page

What does the HTML that React renders to the page look like?

the button is like Click me

From what I know, it's the expected behaviour for the screen reader to read those dynamically rendered inside aria-live. But since it's common, I am hoping there is a solution to it.

Your question made no mention of aria-live. You shouldn't put a whole page within an aria live region — that's not what that is for. And aria live only reads content as text.

I got point, @sean. But it's a React component, which is dynamically rendered, so it should be inside the aria-live. Otherwise, the SR won't read it.

Is the content an alert? Or are you just navigating to a new page?

aria-live is for notifying users about small dynamic updates to parts of a page's content, not for reading out the whole contents of a page. That would be overwhelming to users, and potentially prevent them from navigating the page's content in their own way at their own pace. And as you've encountered, aria-live just announces the text.
When navigating to a new page in a SPA, it's best practice to set focus to the start of the new page's content—such as an h1—and let users navigate on their own from there. Additionally, you could use a small offscreen aria-live="polite" region to announce to users that they've navigated to a new page (e.g. "Navigated to Home").

Thanks for your reply, @sean. As mentioned in the description, it's navigating to a new page. The whole new page is dynamically rendered. So, for the SR to read the page after the page loads(not when tabbing into elements), the component B must be inside aria-live. I don't think it's a choice.

You shouldn't be forcing a screen-reader to read a whole page on page load. That's the equivalent to automatically scrolling down a page for a sighted user to read. Instead, let people navigate on their own, at their own speed. Please read my answer more carefully, or provide more information and context as to why you feel it's not a choice.

Unfortunately it's the requirement to let SR to read the content from top to bottom on page load.

Requirement from whom?

It's mentioned in the story I am working on :(

If the requirement is to make a screen reader automatically read the whole page, it's a bad requirement that goes against accessibility best practices and you should push back on it. It could also be that the requirement is trying to say that the page should be easily readable by a screen reader, but not automatically. But there's no way to force a screen reader automatically read a page in screen reader mode. No one is doing that.

For your information, screen readers can already automatically read pages from top to bottom if the user wants it. That's a configurable option, for example with Jaws. As an additional argument against your big aria-live, don't go against the user: don't force auto-read to those who have disabled the option. It's even worse: if the option is activated, the whole content might be read twice.
